# Oracle 18.1 sql query error

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an sql query

```
SELECT ("SL/VL".TOTAL_SICK_LEAVE - SUM(EMPLOYEE_INFO.DAYS_TAKEN_SICK))
  FROM EMPLOYEE_INFO
  INNER JOIN "SL/VL"
    ON EMPLOYEE_INFO.EMPLOYEE_NAME = "SL/VL".EMPLOYEE_NAME
  where contract_year='Year 1'and
        employee_info.EMPLOYEE_NAME = :P4_EMPLOYEE_NAME
  GROUP BY "SL/VL".TOTAL_SICK_LEAVE
```

which was giving me the desired results when I had oracle apex 5.1. Now I upgraded my database to oracle 18.1 I am getting the`"ORA-20999: Column name "("SL/VL".TOTAL_SICK_LEAVE-SUM(EMPLOYEE_INFO.DAYS_TAKEN_SICK))" is invalid for the LOV SQL query. Make sure that you use valid alias names for your columns."`

Comment: It appears that 18.1 wants a column alias on the expression `("SL/VL".TOTAL_SICK_LEAVE - SUM(EMPLOYEE_INFO.DAYS_TAKEN_SICK))`.

Comment: If you alias your table, you will only need to suffer quoting "SL/VL" once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that 18.1 wants a column alias on the expression `("SL/VL".TOTAL_SICK_LEAVE - SUM(EMPLOYEE_INFO.DAYS_TAKEN_SICK))`. Perhaps if you redo your SQL as

```
SELECT (s.TOTAL_SICK_LEAVE - SUM(e.DAYS_TAKEN_SICK)) AS SICK_LEAVE_REMAINING
  FROM EMPLOYEE_INFO e
  INNER JOIN "SL/VL" s
    ON e.EMPLOYEE_NAME = s.EMPLOYEE_NAME
  WHERE CONTRACT_YEAR = 'Year 1' AND
        e.EMPLOYEE_NAME = :P4_EMPLOYEE_NAME
  GROUP BY s.TOTAL_SICK_LEAVE
```

the database will be happier.

Comment: THANKS THAT WORKED

Comment: APEX is generally not a fan of columns with no alias.